# Can the closure of isolated point set be uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S\subset [0,1]$ be a countable set, $\bar{S}$ is the closure of $S$. Can $\bar{S}$ be uncountable? I think it can not be, but I can't find a proof.

**Edit:** I just realized that my previous question is trivial. But what I really mean is that suppose $S$ is countable and with *isolated* points can $\bar{S}$ be uncountable?

Comment: What is the closure of the set $$S=\{(\frac mn,\frac1n):m\in\mathbb Z,n\in\mathbb N\}$$ in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Do you mean that it has every point isolated or just some? If the latter, consider $[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q)\cup\{17\}$.

Comment: In $\mathbb R$ let $$S=\left\{\frac12,\frac16,\frac56,\frac1{18},\frac5{18},\frac{13}{18},\frac{17}{18},\frac1{54},\dots\right\},$$ the set of midpoints of the intervals removed in constructing the Cantor set; $S$ is a discrete set (every point is isolated), and its set of limit points is the Cantor set, which is uncountable.

Comment: @bof Nice example!

Answer (score 3):

Closure of the rationals $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is $\mathbb{R} \cap [0,1]$, which is uncountable.

Comment: Yeah... When I submited the question, I realized it is trivial...